# WSO2 APIM publisher keeps on redirecting once the password is changed

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have changed the password of WSO2 APIM, then when I try to access the publisher it keeps on redirecting and never loads. Tried clearing the cache too but didn't help.

Anyone experienced similar issue?

Thanks
Susi

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: [2023-01-03 01:26:30,625] ERROR - introspect:jag {"data" : null, "xhr" : {}}
[2023-01-03 01:26:30,975]  WARN - DataEndpointGroup No receiver is reachable at URL Endpoint/Endpoints [tcp://10.5.0.6:9611], will try to reconnect every 30 sec
[2023-01-03 01:26:30,986]  INFO - DataBridge user admin connected
[2023-01-03 01:26:30,993] ERROR - Authenticator wrong userName or password
[2023-01-03 01:26:30,993] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.5.0.6:9711.

Comment: Can you be specific on whether you have changed the Admin credentials or have you changed the password of a non-admin user?

Answer (score 0):

had same problem, solved it by changing the admin username/password directly on the deployment.toml, in this section

```
[super_admin]
username = "admin"
```

Just change the password here and it will work.